# How do I calculate the battery drain for a particular app using dumpsys batterystats?

Tags: android, adb, battery

I am new to Android and adb commands. I have executed the following command in a terminal: `adb shell dumpsys batterystats --charged com.google.android.youtube`. This gives me the estimated power use in mAh, as shown below. I have two questions:

What does `computed drain: 93.8`  mean and can I use this to calculate the percentage of power consumed by particular app?

```
adb shell dumpsys batterystats --charged com.google.android.youtube 

Estimated power use (mAh):
    Capacity: 2390, Computed drain: 93.8, actual drain: 0.00000000
    Screen: 52.5
    Cell standby: 23.3
    Uid u0a96: 6.26
    Uid 1000: 3.91
```

Comment: "Computed drain is what is estimated to have been spent according to
power_profile.xml. Actual drain is the % drop according to the battery gas gauge.​" From here: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/27698396-what-is-the-difference-between-computed-drain-and-actual-drain. Furthermore, I think you are calculating the battery stats of the youtube app. If you want to find power drain for a specific app, why not insert the package name there instead of YouTube? Did you try this and did it work?

Comment: Actually  I am trying to find how much battery consumed by app in particular time for example if I am watching youtube for (1 or 10) minutes i want to know in that (1 or 10) minutes time how much battery consumed by youtube.

Comment: Why don't you make a small data logger that does that for you? This is a good place to start: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html